# Entity table not created

Tags: 8, database, entities

I use drupal:generate:entity to generate my entity but it doesn't create the database table. Then it result an error when i tried to access to my entity list page.

I tried to launch www.mysite.com/update.php but no databases update was found. Can you help me please ?

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal8db.myc_static_content_entity' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {static_content_entity} base_table) subquery; Array ( ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->getEntityIds() (line 98 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityListBuilder.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\Statement->execute(Array, Array) (Line: 610)
Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{static_content_entity} base_table) subquery', Array, Array) (Line: 81)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS expression
FROM 
{static_content_entity} base_table) subquery', Array, Array) (Line: 508)
Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select->execute() (Line: 245)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query->result() (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query->execute() (Line: 296)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryBase->initializePager() (Line: 224)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query->finish() (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query->execute() (Line: 98)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->getEntityIds() (Line: 80)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->load() (Line: 228)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->render() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityListController->listing('static_content_entity')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 652)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Here is my entity class definition :

```
/**
 * Defines the Static content entity entity.
 *
 * @ingroup static_content_master
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "static_content_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Static content entity"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\static_content_master\StaticContentEntityListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\static_content_master\Entity\StaticContentEntityViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\static_content_master\Form\StaticContentEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\static_content_master\Form\StaticContentEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\static_content_master\Form\StaticContentEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\static_content_master\Form\StaticContentEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\static_content_master\StaticContentEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\static_content_master\StaticContentEntityHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "static_content_entity",
 *   admin_permission = "administer static content entity entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/static_content_entity/{static_content_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/static_content_entity/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/static_content_entity/{static_content_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/static_content_entity/{static_content_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/static_content_entity",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "static_content_entity.settings"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: I uninstalled my module an reinstalled it. I found out that tables were created at the initialization of the module.

Comment: You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled my module and reinstalled it. I found out that tables were created at the initialization of the module.

Comment: Either that or run drush entity-updates. For an existing module that people/sites are using, you want to add an update function to explictly install your entity type.